# How can components communicate in real time in Blazor?

Tags: blazor-client-side

I've create a simple Singleton

```
public class SingletonService
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

I registered it

```
private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<SingletonService>();
}
```

I'm assigning it the value of the counter

```
@code {
   private int currentCount = 0;

   private void IncrementCount()
   {
    currentCount++;
    singleton.Value = currentCount;
  }
}
```

Here, I'm incrementing the value of the counter, but nothing is happening in other components

[image]

Only when I navigate to a different route that those values propagate to other components that are using the same services

[image]

Is that the correct behaviour? If so, I do I communicate in real time among components?

Thanks for helping